# Index.html in react build folder not working

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. Just started yesterday.

My project run fine with npm start.

I used "npm run build" and it went fine.

But when I try to run the index.html in build folder with vscode live server I get these errors

[image]

Why are they occuring and how do I fix them ?

Comment: You can try another server (e.g. **http-server** : https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to see if this is something vscode-related.

Comment: It gives an error that says bad request

Comment: The contents of the build folder can be run only when on a web server. And because VSCode isn't a server, neither is your local machine, you can't run it directly. You can try `npm run serve` and see if that helps

Comment: Yes I tried with : npx serve -s build , and it worked fine  Thanks